# Significance of '.' in the PATH or any other environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I want to understand the difference between the following two ways to set the PATH variable, one involving '.' and one without it

`set PATH=.;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.202.08\bin;%PATH%`
and
`set PATH=C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.202.08\bin;%PATH%`

what does adding the dot in front of the directory path does?

Comment: It is short-hand for "current directory".  It does not belong in PATH, the OS already looks in the current directory.

Comment: @HansPassant, that's not correct in general. Since Vista, at least `CreateProcessW` and the CMD shell check [`NeedCurrentDirectoryForExePathW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-needcurrentdirectoryforexepathw). If the environment variable "NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath" is set, then this function is true (i.e. the current directory is added implicitly after the application directory) only if the path is qualified with at least one backslash (not forward slash).

Comment: If the "NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath" environment variable is set to make executable search more secure, as described in the previous comment and link, then a system configuration can still be reasonably secure if "." is manually added to `PATH` after the system directories -- preferably at the end.

Comment: so adding '.' to the environment variable includes everything there is in the current path? while without '.' it only adds the path that is specified, in the above example ```C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.202.08\bin``` and nothing else.

Comment: Again, the system evaluates "." as the process working directory (i.e. `__CD__`). By default, `CreateProcessW` searches the application directory (i.e. `__APPDIR__`), ".", "%SystemRoot%\System32", "%SystemRoot%\System", "%SystemRoot%", and the directories in `PATH`. But if "NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath" is defined, then "." is not implicitly searched unless the searched name contains at least one backslash (e.g. "eggs\spam.exe"). Otherwise, in this case, given the name has no backslash, we can insert "." in `PATH` (preferably at the end) to always search the current directory.

Comment: Thanks @ErykSun, I will like to mark it as answer.